# Radius of convergence and upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ with radius of convergence $L$. Let $l$ be such that $0<l<L$. Show that there exists a constant $A$ not dependent on $k$ such that
$\sup_{|x|<l} |g^{(k)} (x)| \leq Ak!$.

My thoughts are as follows: if we consider the case $c_n = 1$ then $L = 1$. For the series to converge, $|x| < 1$. Differentiate $g(x)$ $k$ times gives

$$
g^{(k)} (x) = \sum_{n = k}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}
$$
For any $l: 0<l<L = 1$, we have
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k} < \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \leq n!
$$
In this case $C = 1$ is a constant that satisfies our requirement.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? What have you tried, and what don't you understand?

Comment: @user38584 I have thought about this for the case $c_n = 1$ (updated in the post) but I'm not sure how to go about $c_n$ (which may not be constant) in general.